# Why does calling flatMap on a List of Integers fail?

Tags: scala

I have the following code:

```
val input: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

and I want to call `flatMap` on it, but it requires me to pass a function which produces a `String`, i.e. if I try this:

```
input.flatMap(x => x + 1)
```

then I get the following error:

> :9: error: type mismatch;  found   : Int(1)  required: String
>                 input.flatMap(x => x + 1)

Can someone explain why this is the case? There are no strings in my original `input` definition, it's a list of `Int`.

Comment: You want to use `map`.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use flatMap this way. flatMap should produce GenTraversableOnce, for example:

```
input.flatMap(x => List(x+1))
```

If you want to just increase each item in list, use *map* method instead

Compilation message about String type required is quite confusing

Comment: Why does the error message say it requires a String?

Comment: That's because the compiler tries its best to find an _implicit_ conversion into a `GenTraversableOnce`, and there's such a conversion from `Int` to `String`, which extends `GenTraversableOnce[Char]`. For example, this code: `input.flatMap(x => x + "1")` compiles and works (although doesn't do what you are probably trying to do, which indeed simply requires `map`).

Answer (score 0):

Consider `Option` as a *container*, with `flatMap` we can `map` the value in the container; note for instance

```
input.flatMap(x => Some(x+1))
List(2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Comment: Although using `Option[T]` is indeed possible, it is side tracking the OP from understand what `flatMap` actually does, and why he actually wants a `map`.